# Java Random.nextInt() repeating numbers only in a loop

Tags: java

I am trying to procedurally generate a world on a 2D grid. For the random numbers generation I am using a **single** *global java.utils.Random* Instance and a seed.
Like this:

```java
public class Game {

    private static final int SEED = 1111;
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random(SEED);
    private static final int roomsCount = generateRandomNumberOfRooms();
}
```

Everything worked just fine untill I wrote this method:

```java
public ArrayList<XYCoords> generateRandomCoordinates(){
        ArrayList<XYCoords> coords = new ArrayList<>(roomsCount);

        for(int i = 0; i < roomsCount; i+=1) {
            XYCoords xy = new XYCoords(RANDOM.nextInt(WIDTH),  RANDOM.nextInt(HEIGHT));
            coords.add(xy);
        }
        return coords;
    }
```

When I execute it I get the list of *XYCoordinates* but they all have the same two *X* and *Y* values, for example (11,20) or (12, 5)... etc. and all the rooms land on the same spot. It looks to me like the call to *RANDOM.nextInt()* in the for loop doesn't update the state of the instance RANDOM.
In all other functions that I call RANDOM.nextInt() it works fine. Some of them use for loops too. The problem is only with this function. It is used once directly in main() and not nested anywhere.
Does anyone have any sense of where the problem might be? I can upload more code if you need, but I think it is irrelevant.

Comment: *the same two X and Y values, for example (11,20) or (12, 5)*. 11 is not the same value as 20. (11, 20) is not the same value as (12, 5). What exactly is the problem? Post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue. We must be able to copy and paste it in our IDE, and run it.

Comment: I guess that OP means that for each execution of his/her app the same pairs of numbers a regenerated, which is expected since the same seed is used. If this is the case, OP should just use a new seed every time (or even better, remove the seed altogether, allowing `Random` to use a new one each time)

Comment: @Cascader that's the right answer

Comment: "I get the list of XYCoordinates but they all have the same two X and Y values" - that indicates you get lists like `(12,5),(12,5),(12,5)...`. If so, then instead of `nextInt(...)` returning the same value it's more probable that all the `XYCoords` instances share the same data. Can you show us that class or ideally a [mcve]? - If it is like Cascader is assuming, i.e. your "problem" is that every time you run the application the coordinates are the same then you need to remove the seed or use a different one each time (such as current system time).

Comment: Did you declare the x y variables in XYCoords as `static`?

Comment: Thanks to all for your suggestions. The right one that solves the problem was from @Joni . The problem indeed was that I was getting list of (12,5), (12, 5) (12,5)... And to be able to pick a seed is a specification requirement, so I cannot leave that.

Comment: This was my first question and I don`t know how to mark your answer as correct. I will try to do it when I come back this evening. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Unwanted behaviour 1***: each application run generates the same values in the same order. The reason is your `RANDOM` object which is instantiated with a seed. Try the following adaption: (Removing the seed, allowing `Random` to give you random values):

```
public class Game {

    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
    private static final int roomsCount = generateRandomNumberOfRooms();
}
```

If you need the seed for some reason, you could try to update the seed at each startup.

Clarification what the seed actually does:

(Note that the seed is also set from the constructor if you provide a seed)

> setSeed
>
> public void setSeed(long seed)
>
> Sets the seed of this random
>   number generator using a single long seed. The general contract of
>   setSeed is that it alters the state of this random number generator
>   object so as to be in exactly the same state as if it had just been
>   created with the argument seed as a seed. The method setSeed is
>   implemented by class Random by atomically updating the seed to (seed ^
>   0x5DEECE66DL) & ((1L << 48) - 1) and clearing the haveNextNextGaussian
>   flag used by nextGaussian(). The implementation of setSeed by class
>   Random happens to use only 48 bits of the given seed. In general,
>   however, an overriding method may use all 64 bits of the long argument
>   as a seed value.
>
> Parameters: seed - the initial seed

***Unwanted behaviour 2***: the cords are all the same after the loop. The `XYCoords` class probably declares the `x` and `y` as `static` variables. **Solution**: Remove the static declaration. As the values are static, the objects share these values as they are bound to the class. The last values which are set are the values you will get if you iterate over all of your `XYCoords` objects.

In general it is a mixture of both things which lead to the result that you get the same values all the time.